# How to symbolize different information that's joined to a single plot in a shapefile

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, cartography

I am a student doing an industrial survey in Windhoek, Namibia.  We mapped different businesses and later did spatial analysis. Questionnaires were handed to different businesses and then that information was entered into an Excel sheet and joined to the erf shapefile using a field `Erf_Number`. I later found out that some businesses from malls and shopping centers are joined to a single erven/plot. How can one visualize them?

---

**[Meaning of erven or erf](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/erven)**:

> erf [ɜːf]
>
> n pl erven [ˈɜːvən]
>
> (Engineering / Civil Engineering) South African a plot of land, usually urban, marked off for building purposes
> [Afrikaans]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In QGIS, one solution could be to use Point Displacement renderer. It will take care of rendering points which are located at the same position. You can see it in action here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M_1m4X9wCpE

Comment: i new here don't have privileges to vote yet

Comment: do you know how yo do Point Displacement rendering in arcmap or any esri suits ?

Comment: Your follow up question about Point Displacement in ArcGIS for Desktop should really be posted as a new Question but there it is known as Disperse Markers which was discussed in this [**blog**](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2008/08/01/how-to-scatter-marker-symbols-for-stacked-or-clustered-point-features/).